# When I use create-vue packaging, there is an unpredictable error, I really do not know what to do

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite, create-vue

```js
[commonjs--resolver] Unexpected token (1060:2) in C:/Users/PC/Desktop/board-pro/node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js
file: C:/Users/PC/Desktop/board-pro/node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:1060:2
1058:   // internals.
1059:   __isSuspense: true,
1060:   {"version":"v16.20.0","versions":{"node":"16.20.0","v8":"9.4.146.26-node.26","uv":"1.43.0","zlib":"1.2.11","brotli"...
        ^
1061:     if (n1 == null) {
1062:       mountSuspense(
error during build:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1060:2) in C:/Users/PC/Desktop/board-pro/node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js
    at Object.pp$4.raise (file:///C:/Users/PC/Desktop/board-pro/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:21621:13)
    at Object.pp$9.unexpected (file:///C:/Users/PC/Desktop/board-pro/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:18829:8)
    at Object.pp$5.parseIdentNode (file:///C:/Users/PC/Desktop/board-pro/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:21557:10)
    at Object.pp$5.parseIdent (file:///C:/Users/PC/Desktop/board-pro/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:21530:19)
    at Object.pp$5.parsePropertyName (file:///C:/Users/PC/Desktop/board-pro/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:21349:109)
    at Object.pp$5.parseProperty (file:///C:/Users/PC/Desktop/board-pro/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:21272:8)
    at Object.pp$5.parseObj (file:///C:/Users/PC/Desktop/board-pro/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:21235:21)
    at Object.pp$5.parseExprAtom (file:///C:/Users/PC/Desktop/board-pro/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:20961:17)
    at Object.pp$5.parseExprSubscripts (file:///C:/Users/PC/Desktop/board-pro/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:20769:19)
    at Object.pp$5.parseMaybeUnary (file:///C:/Users/PC/Desktop/board-pro/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:20735:17)
ERROR: "build:dev" exited with 1.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeNQj.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dk1k.png)

My project can be started normally, There was a problem with the packing, At first, I thought there was a problem with package dependency. I reassembled and changed the version of node, but it still didn't work

Comment: Did you add a new package to your project? if yes. terminate npm run dev. again run npm run dev and after that run npm run build on another terminal.

Comment: Wrap your error message in *Markdown Code Block*  please :)